# Sahi pro Load testing with multiple user

Tags: sahi

i am using Sahi Pro to perform load testing  , as of now i am logging in as a single user to perform load testing , is there  any possibility of doing load test with multiple user logging the application simultaneously .

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can run as many users as you want... but you'll have to write the code to do so yourself.

For example, you could write a single test that randomly selects a username/password from an array and performs some action. You could then add that test multiple times to a suite and run it for as many threads as your system can handle. You could also distribute the tests to multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did a similar test. What you can do is have your data such that you can establish some kind of relation for user. So if your users can be loadUser001, loadUser002 etc.

You can get the thread number in your script as follows

`var $threadNo = _sessionInfo().threadNumber;`

Now you can have an excel sheet with the usernames and passwords, from where you can select user credentials w.r.t thread numbers. So lets say loadUser001 will log into browser with thread number 1 etc.

I hope it makes sense. Try it out and if you have any further query, you can put a sample code of what you tried.